error: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format=]
Compiling the below code without gcc flags doesn't raise any errors but does when I use -Werror, I have been printing memory address with %p flag but apparently I now have to typecast to void* to use the %p flag, what's the required flag to print integer pointers as %ls suggested by the compiler isn't supported in ISO C90?
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int var = 789, *ptr, **ptr1;

    ptr = &var;
    ptr1 = &ptr;

    printf("var: %d\n", var);
    printf("address of var: %p\n", &var);
    printf("address: %p references: %d\n", ptr, *ptr);
    return (0);
}

main.c:18:27: error: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format=]
   18 |  printf("address of var: %p\n", &var);
      |                          ~^     ~~~~
      |                           |     |
      |                           |     int *
      |                           void *
      |                          %ls

also using %ls format specifier:
main.c:19:21: error: ISO C90 does not support the ‘%ls’ gnu_printf format [-Werror=format=]
   19 |  printf("address: %ls references: %d\n", ptr, *ptr);
      |                     ^

I know I have to typecast, but why do I have to do that?

The correct way to print a pointer is with %p conversion specifier, and to cast the type of the pointer to void* ie printf("address of var: %p\n", (void*)&var);. Why? because void* is compatible with any other type of pointers ... but pointers to different types (except void (and possibly unsigned char)) are not necessarily the same size and alignment as any other pointer: they are not compatible.

See C11 6.2.5p28 and C11 6.3.2.3

The message is really quite clear, and the solution should be quite obvious (and you already know it).

Also, unlike eg memcpy(), printf() is a function with a variable number of arguments and the arguments do not get automatically converted to any type other than default argument promotions. In particular values of int* type are not converted.

Historically, there has been word-addressed machines where void* (and char*) were larger than int*. The language was designed to support that.

Do you have to compile for long-obsolete C90? A %ls specifier conforms to all four (!) subsequent versions of the language spec.

@JohnBollinger 4 or maybe 5? After C89/90, I see 5: C94, C99, C11, C17, C23.  (Maybe C17 is not worthy  )

@chux, C94 is not on my list. To the best of my knowledge, some people use that to describe C90 + some technical corrigenda, but however significant the corrigenda may or may not have been, the combination is not a new version of the spec.

C has a number of implicit conversion which happen as part of an assignment, which includes passing named parameters to functions, and one of those implicit conversions is between a void * and any other object pointer.
What makes printf different is that it is a variadic function, where only the first parameter is named.  That means that any parameters that follow don't get converted by these implicit conversion rules.
There's no guarantee that a void * has the same representation as other object pointers (other than character types), so passing an int * to printf with the %p format specifier might not have the expected result as the typical implicit conversion doesn't happen.
Because of this, if a variadic parameter to a function is expected to be a void *, as it is for the %p format specifier, an explicit cast is required.

Examples of systems where sizeof(void*) and sizof(int*) have different representations.

printf requires void * paramamters for %p.
You need to convert other types of pointers.
printf is well known to many compilers and they provide additional diagnostics (beyond required by C standard) when parsing the format string
printf("address: %p references: %d\n", (void *)ptr, *ptr);


ISO C90 does not support the ‘%ls’

Why don't you use wprintf function instead of non standard format?
What is the point of using a prehistoric language standard? Would you use C# 1.0 or python 0.9.0 nowadays?
BTW you can print pointer as integer using uintptr_t and PRIuPTR format.
int main() 
{
    int var = 5
    uintptr_t address = (uintptr_t)&var;
    printf("Address: %" PRIuPTR "\n", address);
    return 0;
}

